# How to Install WordPress and Magento2 in ubuntu 22.04 using apache2?

Tags: 22.04, apache2, wordpress, virtualhost, magento

I hope you can understand what i am going to ask you, about installing two applications in ubuntu using apache2, I installed Magento2 in var/www/html/ and I want to install WordPress on var/www/wordpress so that I can access both the sites independently.
is there any possible way to host the two application on same IP address?

And I tried to follow this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-16-04 6) but they are asking to use the VPS to hosts the two sites and access it independently.

can anyone help me to overcome this situation?

Comment: You can use mod_proxy (if they are different processes) or mod_rewrite (if they are in the same process) in apache2. I'm not familiar how exactly on apache2, but on Nginx, I would filter by Host or Path and send the users to the right service

Comment: Thanks for your valuable answer @DanielT,
Can you suggest me a reference for the Nginx server setup to handle both application in separate URL?